# Ответы, данные до существенной корректировки вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ответы, удаление-ответов

[Данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/517699/199934) ответ ув-мого lexxl абсолютно верен, но в пределах одного файла, о чём можно было бы подумать из [вопроса в изначальном состоянии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/517694/1). После того, как выяснилось, что необходимо произвести замену во множестве файлов, ответ превратился в ошибочный. Он может *а)* сбить с толку людей, зашедших на Stack Overflow со схожей проблемой, *б)* добавить автору ответа негативной репутации.

Что делать в этом и схожих случаях?

Полагаю, необходимо:

1) Уведомить автора, чтобы он удалил либо существенно изменил свой ответ;
2) Если он неактивен/не отвечает, отметить сообщение тревогой.

Или как поступить правильнее?

Comment: Вообще-то не вполне корректно со стороны автора вопроса изменять вопрос после того, как на него получен ответ. Автор ответа может в этой ситуации, по идее, дописать в ответе, что это ответ на вопрос в его первоначальной формулировке.

Answer (score 12):

Если **отвечающий дал ответ, предполагая некоторую интерпретацию вопроса**, а потом выяснилось, что вопрошающий имел в виду другое, то это **ошибка отвечающего**: если вопрос неясен, то правильнее выяснить детали, а не отвечать наугад. В этом случае следует сообщить отвечающему в комментарии, что он ошибся, и отвечающий может выбрать: либо удалить ответ, либо обновить его. В принципе можно воспользоваться и удалением, но обычно это излишне сложная, а потому бесполезная процедура.

Если **вопрошающий изменил смысл вопроса**, то есть если текущая версия противоречит изначальной, а не дополняет её, то это **ошибка вопрошающего**: нельзя изменять смысл вопроса, особенно когда ответы уже даны. В этом случае следует откатить вопрос до изначальной версии (если нет привилегии правки без проверки, то важно указать в комментарии причину отката) и сообщить вопрошающему о нарушении процедуры. Если вопрошающему нужен ответ и на новую версию вопроса, то следует задать новый вопрос и, возможно, сослаться на предыдущий для контекста.

Нужды в использовании тревог в большинстве случаев нет. Выяснение, какой ответ правильнее, находится вне компетенции модераторов. Вот если ваш откат до изначальной версии откатили или набросились с грубостями за объяснение ситуации — здесь модератор может пригодиться.

Comment: К какой категории вы относите пример из вопроса?

Comment: @jfs По-моему, автор вопроса кристально ясно выразил желание делать замену в нескольких файлах: "как без ущерба **проекту**, **пакетно** заменить пробелы на табы" (орфография сохранена), так что это скорее невнимательность отвечающего.

Comment: На основе этой цитаты можно вывести, что несколько файлов необходимо поддерживать—в таком случае ответ не принадлежит ни к первой ни ко второй категории—я бы не стал называть это *"кристально ясно"*, но согласен: нет явной неоднозначности, которую можно и так и сяк интерпретировать. То есть ответ был недостаточен и для первой версии вопроса (автор  текущего мета-вопроса как и автор ответа-примера *просто ошиблись* в чтении вопроса)...

Comment: ...и поэтому является плохим примером к теме: нужно/ **не нужно поощрять людей к изменению их вопросов, таким образом что текущие ответы становятся недействительны** Следует поощрять вопросы с *одной* проблемой Иначе мы получим вопросы-хамелеоны: цепочку правок  где автор очередные *многочисленные* проблемы со своим кодом излагает, а текущие ответы, которые решают только первоначальную проблему проблему становятся недействительными.

Answer (score 6):

Не думаю, что отвечающий в таком случае неправ. Он может Просто приложить к ответу заметку [со ссылкой на соответствующую ревизию вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2948/1): у каждой ревизии есть кнопка "ссылка". А репутацией в таком случае пусть уже рискует вопрошающий.

Comment: Всё же вопрос о действиях не **самого отвечающего**, а **того, кто увидит** его ответ, данный до корректировки. Но если сам окажусь на месте отвечающего, приму к сведению Ваш ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Пример вы выбрали неудачный, даже первая версия вопроса [*"как без ущерба **проекту, пакетно** заменить пробелы на табы"* (выделение @Discord)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2948/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0/2951#comment9661_2951) подразумевает замену в нескольких файлов. Не все "проекты" содержат несколько файлов, но это слово сильно намекает на необходимость поддержки нескольких файлов.

Тот факт, что вы и автор ответа в примере допускаете другую интепретацию, указывает что следовало бы задать два отдельных вопроса:

- Как конвертировать пробелы в отступы в Sublime Text 3 (внутри одного файла)
- Как в проекте, пакетно конвертировать пробелы в отступы в Sublime Text 3 (в нескольких файлах)

Оба вопроса полезны и если в Sublime Text 3 эти задачи могут по-разному решаться, то вопросы не являются дубликатами друг друга.

---

Теперь по заголовку вашего мета-вопроса (не относится к примеру): **Не нужно поощрять людей к изменению их вопросов, таким образом что текущие ответы становятся недействительны**. Следует поощрять вопросы с одной проблемой. Иначе мы получим вопросы-хамелеоны: цепочку правок где автор очередные многочисленные проблемы со своим кодом излагает, а текущие ответы, которые решают только первоначальную проблему проблему становятся недействительными.

Помните, медиана репутации на SO равна единице. Большинство вопросов задаются полными новичками и плохого качества.

Если на вопрос уже дан ответ (в вероятной его трактовке для будущих посетителей из поисковика), то не следует вопрос редактировать, если это делает текущий ответ недействительным. С новой уточнённой проблемой следует задать новый сфокусированный вопрос.