# Обновление вопроса по мере появления ответов

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки

Уже не первый раз замечаю (пока, правда, только за одним участником) такое поведение, как обновление вопроса по мере публикации ответов на него. Ссылки приводить не буду для исключения излишнего нагнетания. Кому интересно, сам всё сможет найти по определённым ключевым словам.

Суть в следующем: задаётся вопрос (нередко, актуальный для широкой аудитории), начинают появляться ответы. На основании этих ответов, ТС неоднократно производит модификации исходного вопроса, помещая в него, в частности, и цитаты из полученных ответов. Всё это выглядит для меня неоднозначно: с одной стороны проблема раскрывается шире, с другой - формат QA превращается в некое подобие форума, да еще и с нарушением причинно-следственной связи.

Что вы думаете, господа, по этому поводу? Нормально ли это для Stack Overflow, можно ли здесь что-то улучшить, и как стоит реагировать сообществу на такой подход к модификации вопросов?

Comment: если правки делают неверными уже данные ответы, то их можно откатить и попросить задать новый вопрос, уже был похожий вопрос на мете

Comment: @Grundy вопрос был про правки, меняющие смысл. А тут вечный UPDэйт какой-то.

Comment: ну так при updате может происходить уточнение исходного вопроса, а может открываться совсем другой, что вполне можно считать сменой смысла основного вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy рекомендую всё же найти такие вопросы и посмотреть самостоятельно :)

Comment: такие вопросы, это какие? :-)

Comment: @Grundy те, о которых речь в моём посте. Неожиданно!

Comment: Насколько я помню, уже подобные случаи разбирались на мете и была договорённость, что изменять вопрос так, что это обесценивает все данные ответы - нельзя. Вот [нашёл](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2948/213987)  например такой случай. Посмотрите: вас устраивает закрытие на дубликат или вы хотите внести уточнения ;) в свой вопрос?

Comment: @AK сейчас, кмк, несколько иная ситуация. Хотя, конечно, многое зависит от того, что подразумевать под обесцениванием ответа. По сути, имеющиеся ответы становятся менее полными, а вопрос всё более общим при каждой такой правке.

Comment: [Пример такого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/934677/317064)

Comment: [Ещё пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/925770/213987) такого вопроса.

Comment: Закрыть бы их, как слишком общие. Потому что в существующем виде читать их невозможно, а редактировать этот автор точно не станет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov закрытие после получения ответа уже не так эффективно. А про чтение согласен на все 200%.