# Как поступать, если вопрос был изменён после написания ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Как мне стоит поступить, если я дал верный ответ на вопрос пользователя, после чего  вопрос был изменён этим пользователем в такой степени, что мой ответ стал недействительным? Нужно ли мне менять свой ответ, подстраиваясь под каждое изменение или есть какой-то вариант более адекватного ситуации поведения?

Comment: Где-то было подобное обсуждение на мете уже. Не могу найти   (｡•́︿•̀｡). Можете поменять ответ. Но я б лучше автору предложил задать отдельным вопросом тогда уж.

Comment: Помните, основная цель не помощь одному конкретному автору вопроса, а составление базы вопросов и ответов для того чтобы они пригодились многим другим людям. Соответственно вопрос стоит вернуть в первоначальный вид и порекомендовать автору задать отдельный новый вопрос.

Comment: Вот что было по данной теме ранее: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2948/213987  и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6181/213987 и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8565/213987 Общее правило затрудняюсь дать, вероятно максимум полезного что я могу повторить - это "кому-то придётся задавать новый вопрос"

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.