# Автор задал новый вопрос, сделав правку в старом

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Вопрос [Алгоритм нахождения НОД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007086/185348) (см. старую версию) был закрыт вчера как «не по теме». Затем автор исправил вопрос, полностью поменяв его содержимое — теперь вопрос выглядит как «*Напечатать столько “*”, сколько было введено в индекс заданного массива*».

По идее нужно откатить вопрос к предыдущей версии и попросить автора задать *новый* опрос.

Но меня смущает, что после этой правки вопрос снова был открыт.

Что вообще нужно делать в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Вот недавно уже [всплывало](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9364/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0) подобное.

Comment: Хм. Что-то просмотрел момент, что после правки это теперь совершенно другой вопрос.

Comment: @Suvitruf понабирали тут ромбоносов ... :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ пора сложить полномочия как профнепригодный   (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: @Suvitruf группу в ВК ещё не забывать админить

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну хватит, а то у меня депрессия разовьётся   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, меня смутило, что после откатки вопрос снова придется закрывать. Ну в общем-то, ясно, что делать :)

Comment: @Suvitruf предлагаю накатить ... т.е. откатить тот вопрос до первой редакции и снова закрыть, как это сделали первые голосующие. А автора попросить задать новый вопрос.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ done.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а зачем его закрывать?

Comment: @Qwertiy домашка (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf, неважно же.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему же, домашки мы закрываем.

Comment: Вопрос был переоткрыт правильно. Не надо объявлять все подряд требующим правки, вводя новичков в заблуждение, тогда и проблемы не будет. В вопросе "алгоритм нахождения НОД на С++" нет ничего, что дало бы основания закрывать его с причиной "не по теме".