# Правильность помощи новичку

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, ответы

Есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075425/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9F-%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-imageview/1075455#1075455). Я написал на него ответ. У пользователя это был не первый вопрос, по данной тематике. Я думаю по вопросу будет видно, особенно знающим людям что человек только начал разработку. Но это сейчас видно, изначально вопрос был вполне себе обычным, я ведь не могу по вопросу определить уровень его знаний)) После того как я начал получать от пользователя комментарии, у меня начали закрадываться подозрения, что человек кое-чего не знает. Как потом выяснили в комментариях что это и правда первый проект, хотя до этого я напомню у него уже были вопросы по данной тематике. У данного ТС возникли вопросы на которые нужно очень много чего писать и получившийся ответ был бы немного не в контексте его проблемы, в итоге я его делегировал на [сайт](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html) для получения необходимых сведений. Правильно ли я поступил делегировав его или нужно было иначе действовать в подобной ситуации? Просто послать его как-то некрасиво, ведь все мы такими были, а расписывать ему простые вещи как-то мне показалось не очень правильно. Вопрос у меня наверное не позволит дать конкретный ответ, но буду благодарен за любые советы как поступать в подобных ситуациях.

Comment: Типичное непонимание ТС, как работает данный ресурс. Сначала вопрос не содержал ни одной строчки кода, только упоминание о нём. Потом, после полученного ответа, вставил получившийся код, и тут же задал фактически новый вопрос -- "Не компилируется, что с ним не так?". Откатил последнию правку. Правильне было бы, не отсылать на сторонние ресурсы, а предложить задать новый вопрос. В текушем вопросе попробовать, либо комментариями, либо  правками, помочь ТС улучшить качество вопроса, который после этого послужил бы ТС примером для нового вопроса.

Comment: Если сайт в самом деле хорош, то после прохождения всех 190 уроков вопросы сюда у ТС исчезнут....

Comment: [help > editing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) + не стоит править вопрос после получения ответов, чтобы не обесценивать их, стоит задать новый, см. [например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2948/213987)

Comment: @avp продолжу за вас, - "и он не вернется"

Comment: @Cerbo, если захочет поделиться, то вернется уже "отвечальщиком" -)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

О как. 
Здравствуйте здесь.
Прошу не искать черную кошку там, где её нет.

Неумение правильно задавать вопрос там это не повод послать. Хотя возможен и такой вариант.
Злого умысла никакого не имел, но вопрос по поводу как тапнуть на ImageView был все же первым моим вопросом по тематике ImageView.

То, что сначала не было кода - в процессе написания вопроса что-то пошло не так, и появилось окно с уже заданным вопросом, который и стал снова редактировать.
В любом случае это не приколы над опытными кодерами.
Просто как правильно заметил Andrew - все мы когда-то чего-то не знали и не умели.

Кстати, просматривая ответы других присутствующих на другие вопросы, часто замечаю что не все оформляют ответы досконально понятным образом. Не всегда новички могут понять какую часть кода, в какой файл и в каком месте следует вставлять. Прошу присутствующих понять что это не критика - это обратная связь от нового пользователя.

P.S. Странно, что моя персона удостоена создания этой темы здесь. Я ни на кого не собирался жаловаться или обсуждать правильность или не правильность поступков собеседников.
Ко всем отношусь с уважением и ничего никому не доказываю.

Comment: Я тоже отношусь к вам с уважением, и постарался помочь, я думаю все знающие люди вам бы помогли, такова политика и нравы данной публики. Просто я задавал вопрос касательно того правильно ли делегировать тс на другой ресурс или же есть какой-то другой вариант решения. Я поэтому сюда и обратился чтобы наше с вами общение было в итоге максимально корректным и не нанесло вам каких-либо моральных травм. Ведь зачастую люди уходят отсюда из-за поведения других пользователей :) надеюсь что я вас не оскорбил данным вопросом здесь

Comment: Спасибо большое за вашу заботу о моем душевном состоянии. Действительно много площадок в сети абсолютно не заинтересованы в долгожительстве своих посетителей на этих площадках.  Здесь же чувствуется внимание к Человеку с первых шагов. Надеюсь мне никогда не захочется уходить отсюда, удастся подружиться с местным народом и принести какую-то пользу в процессе общения.

Comment: @Rus SO тем и хорош, что здесь в принципе можно получить ответ практически на любой вопрос, включая [довольно неординарные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787091/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-svn-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-c-sourceforge). Главное правильно его задать. Правильно заданный вопрос содержит половину ответа.