# Этичность правки вопроса не автором

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Добрый вечер леди & джентльмены.

Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075425/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9F-%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-imageview). Получил ответ. Начал согласно этого ответа проверять полученный код на практике. Результата не добился, в силу своей неопытности.
Полученные ошибки в виде кода и скриншота добавил в свой вопрос, исправив его самостоятельно.

В процессе общения выяснилось что кто-то удалил мои правки моего вопроса - то есть полностью код и скриншот. 
То есть на полпути к решению получил отсутствие в самом тексте вопроса более половины составляющей.

В данном случае я хотел бы спросить, **насколько этично изменять текст вопроса, написанный другим автором?**

Понимаю что более опытные люди могут подкорректировать теги, может быть кому-то режет глаз орфографическая ошибка или какая-то мелочь.
Но, совершенно не приемлемо вносить правки в текст другого автора, затрагивающий более 5% текста, без согласования с самим автором.
Утверждаю это со 100%-ной уверенностью, имея за плечами опыт работы главным редактором серьёзного средства массовой информации.

И да, я понимаю, что задаваемые вопросы собираются в базу, которая потом будет использована. Согласен что эти вопросы и ответы также будут помогать другим пользователям сообщества. Но, в качестве обратной связи для Администрации ресурса, могу сказать, что правка кем-то текста моего вопроса более чем наполовину, мне сегодня была не приятна. 
p.s. Ложечки-то конечно нашлись, но осадочек остался.

Comment: После прочтения этого текста, я действительно подумал, что @0xdb дал маху. А потом нашёл связанный вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10066/Правильность-помощи-новичку

Comment: И что? Там ответ на вопрос об этичности самостийной редактуры?

Comment: @Rus Нет, там нету ответа на ваш текуший вопрос. Там начало истории вашего вопроса, на который вы ссылаетесь. Коротко на ваш вопрос -- не надо изменять вопрос так, что он становится по сути новым вопросом, после того, как вам дали ответ и вы его приняли. Почитайте пожалуйста все комментарии касающиеся правки вопроса, вы их либо не читали, либо не поняли.

Comment: @Rus Здесь больше подходит слово "самочинной" - вместо "самостийной".

Comment: @0xdb Не понимаю как вопрос может стать новым, если последовал совету, применил код, а результат так и не достигнут? Но это по поводу процесса обсуждения того вопроса.  А что по поводу этого вопроса - этичности "самочинной" (как сказал @Igor) правки ?

Comment: @0xdb комментарии все читал, может быть не всё понял. Но ничего страшного, не Боги горшки обжигают.   А по поводу принятия ответа я уже Вам объсянил, поэтому это ни разу не аргумент ни там, ни тем более здесь.

Comment: @Rus _Не понимаю как вопрос может стать новым_ - хорошо, не совсем новый. Точнее сформулировать - новый, вытекающий из предыдущего, т.е. с ним взаимосвязанный. Так понятней? Позволите встречный вопрос - вы смогли бы создать данный в вашей правке код без данного вам ответа? Если - да, то почему вы не опубликовали его сразу когда задали вопрос?

Comment: Так понятно. Но, знаете что я заметил уже месяц читая ruSO? Все, кто имеет в своем активе уже не один десяток написанных софтин, не могут непредвзято отнестись к сложностям первых шагов новичков. Думаю это просто отпечаток опыта. Потому что то, что например для Andrew просто настолько, что даже не стоит это расписывать, то для новичков зачастую является камнем преткновения.  Но, всё же сейчас мы уходим от сути вопроса об этичности правок текстов других авторов. Почему этот вопрос меня так волнует - потому что это граничит с плагиатом, который я в корне не приемлю (давит опыт моей службы).

Comment: @Rus,я сказал бы, что тут принята модель цепочки нескольких вопросов, в противовес последовательности модификаций начального вопроса. Т.е., задали вопрос, что-то получили, что-то обсудили в комментариях. Если в результате возникли связанные вопросы, то оформляете их отдельно, возможно включая в их текст ссылки на предыдущие вопросы. /     Что же касается *этичности*, то скорее я согласен с вами, не дело менять значительную часть авторского текста.

Comment: @avp , понятно, благодарю за объяснение. Просто когда я задавал первые вопросы мне посоветовали не писать много букв в комментариях, а добавить нужное в сам вопрос.  Как я понял километр комментариев это не есть гуд и допускал правки текста своего вопроса.  Хорошо, буду облегчать работу "большому брату" в постройке и прослеживании цепочек моих интересов и действий.

Comment: @avp _не дело менять значительную часть авторского текста_. Дело в том, что откат был на почти первоначальную версию автора. В этой версии правки только косметические изменения от Andrew, к которым у автора претензий нет. Так, что каких либо значительных изменений авторского текста не было.

Comment: @0xdb, раз так, хорошо. Надеюсь, все разобрались что к чему и ни у кого обид не останется

Comment: Ребят, не нужно думать что у меня здесь к кому-то претензии есть. Наоборот, большое спасибо за то, что уделяете внимание. Я только притираюсь к сообществу, сообщество притирается ко мне - надеюсь все будет у нас хорошо. Пройдет какое-то время, и мои первые вопросы мне самому будут видеться смешными. Так что если я кого-то из присутствующих обидел ненароком, то прошу понять и простить как Бороду Галустяна.

Comment: @Rus, не вижу тут упоминания, потому приведу ссылку: [Как лицензируются материалы, которые я публикую на сайт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) . надеюсь, она поможет в осознании поднятых тем про «правки», «этичность», «плагиат» и т.п.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вопрос не в моих авторских правах  в плане последующих затем где-то перепечаток того, что я написал. Вопрос в том, что "соавторы" и "редакторы" могут исказить сам вопрос настолько, что другие понимающие люди не смогут дать ответ в нужном направлении. По моему, во-первых, нужно не рваться в бой с построением и формой вопросов новичков с клавой наперевес, так как не навредить это первое правило. А вот уже во-вторых, можно оттолкнувшись от своего опыта и знаний, начинать писать ответ. ИМХО, вопрос должен быть неприкосновенен для всех кроме самого автора.

Comment: *вопрос должен быть неприкосновенен для всех кроме самого автора* — нет. у базы знаний (которой является данный сайт) — иные приоритеты: вопрос и ответ(ы) должны помогать тем, кто «придёт позже»: их гораздо больше (на порядки), чем один-единственный автор вопроса (и один-единств. автор ответа). и вообще: помощь автору вопроса — это всего лишь мелкий побочный эффект, возникающий в процессе наполнения базы знаний.

Comment: База знаний это сама цель? А я думал поделиться знаниями это цель. Никогда новичок не научится задавать правильно вопрос иначе чем через собственный опыт. А если знатоки через одного будут его вопросы править, то тем более не научится. Когда бабочка выходит из кокона у нее мокрые скомканные крылья. После того как на вылезла, через тренировку своего тела, она расправляет крылья, они высыхают и она начинает летать. Так вот, если бабочку вытащить из кокона, то после того, как её крылья высохнут она просто сдохнет. Потому что летать не сможет - не было у нее тренировок мышц, её добрый дядя вытащил